# Excel - Prevent quotes when using concatenate with new lines

Tags: excel-formula

When using concatenate with char(10), my output ends up being wrapped in quotes when I cut and paste the value to a new application.

e.g. =concatenate("A",char(10),"B") produces:

```
"A
B"
```

in Notepad.

Anyone know how to suppress the quotes? (this only seems to happen with concatenate + new lines).

Comment: Do you see the quotes in the cell itself? If not, where do you see them?

Comment: Ah - sorry - no, I see them when I cut and paste to, e.g., notepad. The quotes are not visible in the cell - only when you cut and paste.

Putting it that way makes me think it's lets to do with 'concatenate' and more to do with Excel's cut-and-paste behaviour ("always add quotes to multi-line cells when copying" or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly a solution to your problem but if you paste it in MS Word, you won't get the quotes. If your requirement is to see the data without quotes, this may help.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. It's a bit of a kludge, but it seems like it's as good as it's going to get, and I would never have thought of testing what Word did, so it's useful.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the annoying quotes by adding "clean" function to the very beginning of your formula, examples:

#### Original formula surrounding result with quotes:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, " ", B1, ".", C1)
```

#### Final formula quotes free:

```
=CLEAN(CONCATENATE(A1, " ", B1, ".", C1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Excel to piece together some xml, so I wanted to retain all the "pretty-print" style white space in the snippets I put in my concatenated input cells.  Then I used the "&" for concatenate as in:  A1&A2&A3 ... and got the same problem described on this post.

Pasting in Word strips off all the indent white space around my tags putting them flush against the margin (not good)

```
    <tag1>
    <tag2>
    <tag3>
    </tag3>
...
```

Using Clean() around it was even worse - it killed all spaces of any kind so my tags came out like this:

```
<tag1><tag2><tag3></tag3><tag2> ...
```

The answer that worked for me was to do this:
in the A1 cell, add a double-quote at the start (which is supposed to mean right-justified text cell).

In the final cell, add a double-quote at the end of the content to be concatenated

The result then looks like this (the desired tagging output):

```
"""
      <tag1>
          <tag2>
             <tag3>
             </tag3>
              ...

 """
```

All white space is now preserved.

although the tripple double-quotes are not ideal, they mark the start and end of a record and represent a character combination that does not exist anywhere else in the content I am trying to concatenate.  That makes it easy in a programmer's text editor to do a global replace that takes them all out and leaves me with what I was trying to piece together in Excel.

If anyone knows a way that eliminates this one manual step, please do post on here as I'd love to see it.

Comment: Try trim() instead of clean(). Or put spaces in the string; A1&" "&A2&" "&A3

Comment: I must try that.  Thanks!  Another bit of weirdness - my xml has attributes on the tags like this <tag attribute="some value">.  These are coming out as double-quotes and I then have to do another global replace to fix that.  It's an easy fix, but it's one more step to remember.